# What is the reason CMOS took over as an inverter for fabrication of gates?

Tags: power, cmos, power-dissipation

I get to know that the static power dissipation is zero in case of CMOS where as there is some static power dissipation in NMOS with saturated load and linear load and with NMOS with depleted load.

What exactly does it mean?

Answer (score 5):

*CMOS took over as an inverter for fabrication of gates?*

1) Not only for inverters (you cannot do much with only inverters) but **logic** (digital circuits) in general.

2) the low power consumption of CMOS is only a secondary effect. The **real** reason that CMOS technology is the dominant technology these days is that it **scales with size**. Meaning that if you make the transistors smaller, the circuits become faster.

Making the transistors smaller is **essential** as that means for a given silicon area, more functionality can be implemented on that same size.

NMOS technlogy for logic is completely obsolete now, this was done in the past because there were no better solutions. Once they figured out how to do CMOS no one needed NMOS anymore. The exception is chips for other applications than logic (like high frequency applications) where **only** NMOS transistors are avaialbel for making logic circuits. But then that is only for logic consisting of a couple of gates, even a simple micro Controller would be to complex and power consuming already.

*there is some static power dissipation in NMOS with saturated load and linear load and with NMOS with depleted load.* That is a very confusing sentence. You should provide more context like a schematic, before anyone can answer that. It probably has to do that with NMOS logic, when the NMOS is **on** a current flows. This current does not flow when the NMOS is off.

Comment: Practically every logic circuit can be realised with the help of inverter.Thats why I used inverter. The main thing I want to know is  static power dissipation.what exactly does it mean?

Comment: That's the power dissipation when the circuit is in a static mode, meaning no change over time. The opposite is dynamic, meanign the input signal changes over time, for example when you apply a 1 MHz clock at the input of an inverter.

Comment: (+1) Maybe adding a couple of words about ECL as an alternative when needing speed (sacrificing power), would fit well with your answer and OP's (admittedly nebulous) question and give it a broader audience.

Comment: @Shivamsuhane I don't know where you take the "practically every … can be made with inverter" from. You can implement any boolean logic impression with every logic technology that ever saw use – otherwise, these wouldn't have started to exist in the first place. And also, Pete Becker's answer explains the static power consumption very well.

Answer (score 2):

If you stop the clock in your circuit, so that it isn’t doing anything, the power it uses is the **static dissipation**. For CMOS, that’s 0; for NMOS it’s something more than 0. To put it the other way around, CMOS only uses power when it changes state, i.e., when a gate **changes** from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0; when it’s doing nothing it uses no power.